# How to store a permanent boolean flag?

Tags: php, mysql, boolean

I have created a web app that has 2 control panels. One for the admin and one for the users. I want the users to be able to perform one specific action from their panel only if the admin sets this action "on" (from his panel) and not being able when he sets it "off".

My app also uses a MySql database.

How can I implement it? Is an extra table with only one field a viable solution? Can I do it by reading a file (maybe JSON)?

**EDIT**: I want the admin to be able to toggle the "on/off" status with a click of a button, so constants are not a solution.

Comment: Yes. The answer is yes.

Comment: Do you want the one flag affect on all users?

Comment: Yes with database or yes with json or other file? Also, I 'd like the most "right" and effecient solution not just one that works. An extra table doesn't seem to me like a good solution. Correct me if I m wrong

Comment: @hindmost yes. I want to check if it is "on" every time before the specific action is going to take place.

Comment: You could set it in the database and consult that every page load, or you could have a configuration file that you load it in as a PHP constant: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php which will be usable everywhere in your script and won't require a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to store a single value you don't need to use DB. You may simply store this flag in a file as serialized value.
Below is simplified example.

```
define('PERM_FLAG_FILE', 'perm_flag.dat');
$PERM_FLAG = false;

function loadFlag() {
    global $PERM_FLAG;
    return file_exists(PERM_FLAG_FILE)? unserialize(file_get_contents($PERM_FLAG)) : false;
}

function saveFlag() {
    global $PERM_FLAG;
    file_put_contents(PERM_FLAG_FILE, serialize($PERM_FLAG));
}

function setFlag($v) {
    global $PERM_FLAG;
    $PERM_FLAG = (bool)$v;
}
```

Comment: I finally did it with a JSON file. I think there isn't also need to define a constant like your example.

Comment: @Antonis Grigoriadis As I wrote that's simplified example and it shouldn't be considered as a ready solution. However you could upvote my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

A database query could be used every time the action is used but if it is more general and you are going to be using this a lot, I would look into PHP constants. You could set it in a configuration file like:

**Config.php**

```
define('USER_CAN_MODIFY', true);
```

**Other.php**

```
if ((defined('USER_CAN_MODIFY') and USER_CAN_MODIFY === true) { }
```

Constants have a global scope and cannot be changed once set.

Comment: But how can I change it with a click of a button (until it is pressed again)? If I have the define() in a Config.php that I include in every controller of my app, every time the script loads it will be true! That means only manually?

Comment: A constant cannot change dynamically so this is not a solution:(

Comment: Then you would have to define it dynamically at the beginning of the script.  It doesn't have to be static in your config file, that was just an example, but once it is set in the script, it cannot be modified.   Realistically, you would never need to change a setting like this after it is set, you just have to go about defining it from a query.  Ways you could go about this is running a DB query or a loading parameters from a saved INI file in the config.php.  I was just giving you a static example that would avoid extra DB queries every time the page is loaded.